# Verification failed: (15) Access denied error

Tags: secure-boot

[image]

I added /boot/efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi to the database of accepted UEFI secure boot keys, but in still running into this when I try to boot Ubuntu.

When I add grubx64.efi to the database as well, Ubuntu loads just fine, although I thought shimx64.efi is the signed key not grubx64.

What is going on here and how can I fix this. I don't see why this is happening.

Comment: I just restart my pc and pressed esc and continue to boot into windows and then reinstall linux it works for me . I dont have much data on linux

Answer (score 4):

**You will need to disable secure boot.** This is how I did for my windows 10, hp laptop
https://support.hp.com/nz-en/document/c04784866

It worked for me. After disabling secure boot. Restart your computer and keep on pressing ESC (or ant other key according to your laptop) until you get boot options then press F9 and it will allow you to choose boot to windows or linux

Comment: I came across this question and found it useful in a somewhat different setting: I wanted to wipe a hard disk (using a USB stick booting into Youwipe). The laptop had had Ubuntu 20.04 installed, with secure boot enabled. 

To get it to boot from the USB stick, I had to select "reset secure boot keys to factory defaults" in the HP BIOS (see the link in this answer).